# How to take the derivative of an integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\sqrt y} \exp\left(-{\frac{x^2}{2}}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x\right).$$

I try to integrate first and then do the differentiation but it's not easy. I want to know other way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Leibniz rule for differentiation under the integral sign

Comment: it is $$1/2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-y/2}}\sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {\pi }\sqrt {y}}}$$

Comment: the first derivative is more than easy, you just need to get derivative the boundary and then times the function under integral! see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that in general

$$f(t)=\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}g(u) du\implies f'(t)=g(b(t))\cdot b'(t)-g(a(t))\cdot a'(t)$$

thus

$$\frac d{dy}\left(\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_0^{\sqrt y} e^{\frac {-x^2}{2}}dx\right)=\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\sqrt y)'e^{\frac {-y^2}{2}})=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt y}\,e^{\frac {-y}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We apply the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

This gives us,

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left( e^{-(\sqrt{y})^2}\cdot\left(\frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{y}\right) - e^{-0^2}\cdot\left(\frac{d}{dy} 0\right)\right),\\
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}},\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$$

Answer (score 0):

the first derivative is :
$$ (\frac{2}{{\sqrt{2\pi}}})\frac{1}{2{\sqrt{y}}}e^{-x^{2}/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you define $F(y)=\int_0^ye^{-\frac{x^2}2}~dx$ then by fundamental lemma of calculus $F$ is differentiable with $F'(y)=e^{-\frac{y^2}2}$.

We use $\frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{y}=\frac1{2\sqrt{y}}$ and the chain rule and get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\sqrt y} \exp\left(-{\frac{x^2}{2}}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x\right)&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi}}F(\sqrt{y}) \right)\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}F'(\sqrt{y})\cdot\frac1{2\sqrt{y}}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{y}2}.
\end{align*}